# Is there any difference between these two ways to get lowercase `Vec<char>`

Tags: rust

Is there any difference between these two ways to get lowercase Vec. This version iterates over chars, converts them and collects the results:

```
fn lower(s: &str) -> Vec<char> {
    s.chars().flat_map(|c| c.to_lowercase()).collect()
}
```

and this version first converts to a `String` and then collects the chars of that:

```
fn lower_via_string(s: &str) -> Vec<char> {
    s.to_lowercase().chars().collect()
}
```

Comment: A single "character" can take multiple `char`s, so I expect it's possible to break the former in some non-English language. Say, dotless and dotted Is from Turkish may do the trick if (de)normalized. Do not work with `char`s unless you need unicode codepoints.

Answer (score 4):

A short look at the code for [`str::to_lowercase`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.59.0/src/alloc/str.rs.html#385) immediately revealed a counterexample: It appears that Σ at the end of words receives special treatment from `str::to_lowercase`, which `chars()`-then-`char::to_lowercase` can't give, so the results differ on `"xΣ "`.

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=236a7a908ad44291e326cfdb4cdfedfd)

---

Before looking at the code of `std::to_lowercase`, I thought: Well, it should be really easy to find a counterexample with a fuzzer. I messed up the setup at first and it didn't find anything, but now was able to get it right, so I'll add it for completeness:

```sh
cargo new theyrenotequal
cd theyrenotequal
cargo fuzz init
cat >fuzz/fuzz_targets/fuzz_target_1.rs
```

```rust
#![no_main]
use libfuzzer_sys::fuzz_target;

fuzz_target!(|data: &str| {
    if data.to_lowercase().chars().collect::<Vec<_>>()
        != data
            .chars()
            .flat_map(|c| c.to_lowercase())
            .collect::<Vec<_>>()
    {
        panic!("Fuxxed: {}", data)
    }
});
```

```sh
cargo fuzz run fuzz_target_1 -Zbuild-std
```

That spat out `"AΣ#ӮѮ"` after 8 million iterations.

Comment: Nice find! I did not even consider actual functional differences to be honest, and was just wondering if there was a performance difference.

Answer (score 2):

Completing the answer of @Caesar, in case the behavioral difference doesn't matter, there is still a performance difference.

[`String::to_lowercase()` allcates a new `String` and fills it with the characters](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/src/alloc/str.rs.html#383). `char::to_lowercase()` only does that on-the-fly. So the former is expected to be much slower. I don't think there can't be a version of `String::to_lowercase()` that returns an iterator and avoids the penalty of the allocation, just that it hasn't done yet.